# @NotNull type annotation - Solrj

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have solr schema where almost every field is required=true.

I am using following POJO to persist data in solr

```
@Field(value = "id")
private String id;

@Field(value = "entity_id")
private Long entityId;
...
```

Now before sending it to solr, I am currently checking explicitly each field for null. 
Is there any annotation like @NotNull or @Field attribute like required=true so that I need not to check them ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I do not believe that SolrJ has this capability.  (Source - I looked at the source code.  Field does not have this defined, nor are there other beans that might be useful.)

Comment: thx josh for replying. I also searched but not able to get any. It seems i have to continue explicit validation.